# Conditional arguments in terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds

I'm creating a RDS database in terraform and I don't know how to declare an argument if a var equals to any value. My code:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "mariaDB" {
  for_each = var.rds_databases[terraform.workspace]

  identifier           = "api-mariadb-${each.value.name}"
  allocated_storage    = each.value.allocated_storage
  storage_type         = each.value.storage_type
  engine               = each.value.engine
  engine_version       = each.value.engine_version
  allow_major_version_upgrade = each.value.allow_major_version_upgrade
  auto_minor_version_upgrade = each.value.auto_minor_version_upgrade
  instance_class       = each.value.instance_class
  name                 = each.value.dbname
  username             = each.value.dbusername
  password             = each.value.dbpassword
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.subnet-mariadb[each.value.name].name
  skip_final_snapshot  = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.rds_SG.id]
  storage_encrypted    = true
  
  snapshot_identifier = each.value.snapshot_identifier  <--- THIS VALUE ONLY HAVE TO BE DECLARED IF THE VAR SNAPSHOT_IDENTIFIER != null
```

Explanation: I have to declare the snapshot_identifier only if not equals to 'null' (for example). Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This resource should function as desired as it is currently written. If `each.value.snapshot_identifier` is `null`, then the argument will be omitted. If it has been assigned a value, then the value will likewise be assigned to the argument `snapshot_identifier`. Could you provide more information about how observed behavior is different from expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

For resource configuration arguments, omitting an argument is exactly the same as setting it to `null`, because internally `null` is how Terraform represents omitted optional arguments.

If you need it to be conditional then you can write any expression that will return `null` in the case where you want it to be unset. If your `each.value.snapshot_identifier` is *already* `null` in that case, as your comment suggests, then what you have already tried should be sufficient to get your intended effect.